# Single Windows User using less than the total amount of resources?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

[image: Improvement]

The percentages of resources aren't the same, even though there's only a single user. Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Can you provide some addditional details by running RAMMap?

Comment: System  and NT User are also users.

Answer (score 0):

On modern desktop operating systems, many processes and drivers are always running—even when no user is logged in at all. These components also consume resources (like RAM). Hence the discrepancy between usage attributed to user sessions and totals.